# Podio API - How to (bulk) add a comment to multiple items

Tags: php, podio

Using the Podio PHP API how can I add a comment to multiple items in a single call? (or some alternative method)

I can obviously loop over each item and use `PodioComment::create($type, $id, $atts)`, which is fine for small numbers of items, but would run in to the rate limit when updating thousands of items.

Answer (score 0):

Podio doesn't support bulk comment creation.

Comment: Thanks - I understood from the docs that this is the case... so, what's the alternative?

Comment: If you need to add 1000 comments, you'll have to make 1000 API calls. One by one. There are no other options or alternatives :)